# ExtJS 4.2: make store local when data loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, proxy, store, extjs4.2

I want to make store local when it already loaded all possible data for grid to prevent unnecessary requests to server.

As I understood, I need to change type of proxy to 'memory', but I still did not get needed result.

Could anybody provide me with solution?

Comment: What kind of unnecessary queries you say?

Comment: I mean, that when store get all data from server, there is no need to send other requests to server, for example, when I switch to other page of the grid. So, as I understood, the idea is to make store local and keep all data

Comment: But the store will only load one page, if you are using the correct pagination. The store have not data of the other pages.

Comment: The idea is that my store can change pageSize and when I get big pageSize and all data on one page, after next changing of pageSize on smaller, I already have all needed data in my store.